# .htaccess force browser side cache

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess code like

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png|css|swf|php)$">
  Header add "Expires" "Mon, 28 Jul 2014 23:30:00 GMT"
  Header add "Cache-Control" "max-age=31536000"
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault A604800
 ExpiresByType text/css A604800
 ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
 ExpiresByType image/png A604800
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
 ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A604800
</IfModule>
```

The problem is that it still checks the server if the file has been modified and then returns 304 Not Modified. I want it to use cache by default i.e. the local browser cache and not make a round trip to the server at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `ETag` present as well?

Comment: How do you switch off ETag

Comment: `FileETag None` -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#fileetag

Answer (score 1):

You can't force a client to do what you want. All things given in your configuration are "optional recommendations" for a client. You only have control over the server and have no influence on the client's behavior even if you give them advices.

Comment: @Rolando Cruz: Please do not edit someone else's post for content.

Comment: I understand that. But most browsers will follow these recommendations. Am not saying that all browsers have to follow it.